# Jquery multicomplete suggestion box control with keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

This code work perfectly. but the suggested text can't control using keyboard
when arrow key up and down. i want to control this suggested text using keyboard 
how can i do this. please help..................

```js
/*
 * 
    * jQuery MultiComplete
    * =====================
    * Written by Tom Hallam
    * http://tomhallam.github.com/jQuery-Multicomplete/
    * Licenced with the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0) licence
    * See: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 * 
 */

(function ($) {

    $.fn.multicomplete = function (options) {

        // Set up the default options
        var defaults = {

            // Debug mode provides verbose error messages
            debug: true,

            // Source
            source: [],
            
            // AJAX Method (if source is a URL)
            method: 'POST',

            // Minimum length before a search can be triggered
            minimum_length: 3,
            
            // Delay before performing a search, ignored if source is local
            search_delay: 500,
            
            // Case sensitive search?
            case_sensitive: false,
            
            // Highlight found words?
            highlight_results: true,
            
            // Left offset for results panel
            offset_left: 0,
            
            // Top offset for results panel
            offset_top: 5,
            
            // Result template
            result_template: function(row) {
                // -- Please fill this in!
            },
            
            // Events -------
            // On result click
            result_click: null,
            
            // On form submit
            form_submit: null
            
        }, 
        
        // Extend the base object
        settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
        
        // Object to keep track of our timers
        var timers = [],
        // And our result groups
            groups = {}, 
        // The results themselves
            results = [],
        // And the query
            query = '';

        // Iterate over the selected elements and apply the behavior.
        return this.each(function () {
            multicomplete_init($(this));
        });
        
        // Bootstrapper function to attach events to the elements selected
        function multicomplete_init(el) {
            
            // Create a unique ID for this element       
            id = 'multicomplete-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            $(el).data('multicomplete-id', id);
            
            // Make a new key in our timer object
            timers[id] = {};
            
            // We need to set a timer for input to trigger based on a delay
            $(el).on('keyup', function() {
                
                // Keep a local copy of the value
                query = $(this).val();
                
                // Clear any old timers
                window.clearTimeout(timers[id]);
                
                // If there's nothing left in the input box, do nothing and hide my result panel
                if(query.length == 0) {
                    $('.panel-multicomplete-results.' + id).hide();
                    return;
                }
                                
                // Reset the results array
                results = [];
                
                // Make sure the query is hitting the minimum length constraint
                if(query.length > settings.minimum_length) {
                
                    // Where are we sending this search?
                    switch(typeof(settings.source)) {
                        case 'string':
                            timers[id] = window.setTimeout(function(){ 
                                multicomplete_searchajax(function() {
                                    multicomplete_render(el);
                                }); 
                            }, settings.search_delay);
                            break;
                        case 'object':
                            multicomplete_searchobject();
                            multicomplete_render(el);
                            break;
                    }

                
                }
                
            }).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
            
            // Hide the DIV when someone clicks outside of the result pane.
            $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
                if($('.panel-multicomplete-results.' + id).has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    $('.panel-multicomplete-results.' + id).hide();
                }
            });
            
        }
                
        // Parse a result group 
        function multicomplete_parsegroup(group_results, group_name) {
                        
            // Loop through the group
            $(group_results).each(function(index, row) {
                
                for(var field in row) {
                    
                    // No numbers (for now)
                    if(typeof row[field] == 'number') {
                        return true;
                    }
                    
                    if(typeof row[field] == 'object') {
                        multicomplete_parsegroup(row);
                    }
                    else {
                        // If we find a result then push into our results array.
                        if(multicomplete_match(row[field])) {
                            results.push({
                                'field': field,
                                'row': row,
                                'group': group_name
                            });
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                               
            });
            
        }
        
        // Does this string match the query
        function multicomplete_match(field) {
            if(settings.case_sensitive == true) {
                return field.indexOf(query) > -1;
            }
            else {
                return field.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            }
        }
        
        // Search an object
        function multicomplete_searchobject() {
            
            if(settings.source.length == 0) {
                if(settings.debug == true) {
                    alert('Source was set to an array, but the array was empty.');
                }
            }
            
            // Loop through the source
            for(var group_name in settings.source) {
                if(settings.source[group_name].length)
                    groups[group_name] = multicomplete_parsegroup(settings.source[group_name], group_name);
            }
            
        }

        // Search an AJAX endpoint
        function multicomplete_searchajax(callback) {
            
            // Perform the remote call.
            ajax = $.ajax({
                'type': settings.method,
                'url': settings.source,
                'dataType': 'json',
                'data': {
                    'query': query
                },
                'success': function(data) {
                    
                    // Loop through the source
                    for(var group_name in data) {
                        if(data[group_name].length)
                            groups[group_name] = multicomplete_parsegroup(data[group_name], group_name);
                    }
                    
                    // Call the callback
                    callback.call(this, data);
                    
                },
                'error': function(error) {
                    if(settings.debug == true) {
                            if(error.status == 412) {
                                alert('Your remote data source is not valid JSON! Remember to use double quotes instead of single.');
                            }
                            if(error.status == 404) {
                                alert('Your remote data source does not exist on this server.');
                            }
                            if(error.status == 500) {
                                alert('The remote server encountered an error whilst processing your source.');
                            }
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }
        
        // Render a search result
        function multicomplete_render(el) {
            
            // Where is the element
            l = el.offset().left,
            t = el.offset().top,
            mc_html_class = 'panel-multicomplete-results ' + el.data('multicomplete-id'),
            mc_class = '.panel-multicomplete-results.' + el.data('multicomplete-id');
            
            // Is there already a results div for this element?
            if($(mc_class).length == 0) {
                
                // Build the div
                $('<div class="' + mc_html_class + '"></div>').css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'left': (l + settings.offset_left),
                    'top': (t + $(el).height() + settings.offset_top)
                }).appendTo('body');
                
            }
            else {
                $(mc_class).empty().show();
            }
            
            // Were there any results?
            if(results.length == 0 && !$(mc_class + ' .panel-no-results').length) {
                $('<div class="panel-no-results">No results found</div>').appendTo(mc_class);
            }
            else {
                
                // Create a results div
                $('<div class="results"></div>').appendTo(mc_class);
                
                // Loop through the results and group them again
                $(results).each(function(index, result) {
                   if($(mc_class + ' .results .' + result.group).length == 0) {
                       $('<div class="group ' + result.group + '"><div class="group-title">' + result.group + '</div><div class="group-items"></div></div>').appendTo(mc_class + ' .results');
                   } 
                   
                   // Cache the result row
                   r = $('<div class="result"></div>').appendTo(mc_class + ' .results .' + result.group + ' .group-items');
                   
                   // Get the HTML for the result template
                   result_tmpl = settings.result_template.call(this, result.row, result.group, result.field);
                   
                   // Apply the click action
                   $(result_tmpl).on('click', function() {
                       
                       if(typeof settings.result_click == 'function') {
                           settings.result_click.call(this, result.row, result.group); 
                       }
                       else {
                           multicomplete_defaultclick(result.row, result.group, el);
                       }
                       
                   }).appendTo(r);
                   
                });
                
                // Apply a clearfix to the groups
                $('<div class="clearfix"></div>').appendTo(mc_class + ' .results .group');
                
                // If we have the highlight option turned on then do that
                if(settings.highlight_results == true) {
                    multicomplete_highlight($(mc_class + ' .results').get(0), query.toUpperCase());
                }
                                
            }
            
        }
        
        // Default click action for a result
        function multicomplete_defaultclick(result, group, el) {
            
            // Is there even a form?
            if($(el).closest('form').length == 0) {
            
            }
            
            else {
            
                // Override the form submit to do some funky tings
                $(el).closest('form').on('submit', function(e) {

                // Check if we've already modified the form
                if($(this).data('multicomplete-modified') == true) {
                    $(this).submit();
                }
                else {

                    // Stop the form from submitting
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Modify the element
                    if(!!el.attr('name')) {
                        old_name = el.attr('name');
                        el.attr('name', el.attr('name' + '-mc-dummy'));
                    }

                    // Create a new hidden element with the ID
                    $('<input type="hidden" name="' + old_name + '" value="' + (!!result.id ? result.id : JSON.stringify(result)) + '" />').insertAfter(el);

                    // Add the checkpoint on to the form
                    $(this).data('multicomplete-modified', true);

                    // Submit the form
                    $(this).submit();

                }

                });
            
            }
            
        }
               
        /*
        
        highlight v3
        Highlights arbitrary terms.
        <http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html>
        MIT license.

        Johann Burkard
        <http://johannburkard.de>
        <mailto:jb@eaio.com>

        */
        function multicomplete_highlight(node, pat) {
            var skip = 0;
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                    spannode.className = 'highlight';
                    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                    skip = 1;
                }
            } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                    i += multicomplete_highlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
                }
            }
            return skip;
        }
                
    }
})(jQuery); 


$(document).ready(function() {
               $('#input-multicomplete').multicomplete({
                   minimum_length: 1,
                   result_template: function(result, group, matched_field) {
                        tmpl = '<div>';
                        if(!!result.image) {
                            tmpl += '<div class="image"><img src="' + result.image + '" /></div>';
                        }
                        tmpl += '<div>' + result.name + '</div>';
                        if(!!result.address) {
                            tmpl += '<div class="meta">' + result.address + '</div>';
                        }
                        // Only display this field if something was matched in it
                        if(!!result.cuisine && matched_field == 'cuisine') {
                            tmpl += '<div class="cuisine">Cuisine offered: ' + result.cuisine + '</div>';
                        }
                        tmpl += '</div>';
                        return tmpl;
                   },
                   result_click: function(row, group) {
                       alert('You chose "' + row.name + '" in ' + group);
                   },
                   source: {
    "Attractions": [
        {
            "name": "The Tower of London",
            "address": "London, EC3N 4AB",
            "image": "http://www.hrp.org.uk/Images/TOL_Main.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Camden Lock Market",
            "address": "1 Kentish Town Road, London, NW1 8",
            "image": "http://www.london-attractions.info/images/attractions/camden-market.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Anne Frank Museum",
            "address": "Prinsengracht 267, 1000 AS, Amsterdam",
            "image": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/AnneFrankHouseAmsterdamtheNetherlands.jpg/220px-AnneFrankHouseAmsterdamtheNetherlands.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "Hotels": [
        {
            "name": "The Ritz",
            "address": "150 Piccadilly, London, W1J 9BR",
            "image": "http://www.londonhotels.net/images/photogallery/the-ritz-london/the-ritz-london.jpg"
        },
         {
             "name": "51 Buckingham Gate",
             "address": "51 Buckingham Gate, London, SW1E 6AF",
             "image": "http://static.laterooms.com/hotelphotos/laterooms/193559/gallery/51-buckingham-gate-london_060620111405093617.jpg"
         },
         {
             "name": "Hotel de l'Europe",
             "address": "2–14 Nieuwe Doelenstraat, Amsterdam, 1012 CP ",
             "image": "http://www.concierge.com/images/cnt/lists/goldlist06/europe/netherlands/amsterdam/hotel_de_leurope/amsterdam_hotel_002p.jpg"
         }
    ],
    "Restaurant": [
        {
            "name": "Petrus",
            "address": "1 Kinnerton Street, Knightsbridge, London, SW1X 8EA",
            "image": "http://berkshirereview.net/images/petrus_london_dining.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Vermeer",
            "address": "Prins Hendrikkade 59-72, 1012 AD Amsterdam ",
            "image": "http://www.restaurantvermeer.nl/Portals/7/UltraPhotoGallery/3425/45/[7].Vermeer---desert-2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
               }); 
            });
```

```css
/* DEMO STYLES */
            
            .result .image {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            
            .result .image img {
                width: 32px;
                height: 32px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 1px;
            }
            
            .result .meta {
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #666;
            }
            
            .result a {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            
            .result:hover {
                background-color: #f7f7f7;
            }
            /*
 * 
    * jQuery MultiComplete
    * =====================
    * Written by Tom Hallam
    * http://tomhallam.github.com/jQuery-Multicomplete/
    * Licenced with the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0) licence
    * See: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
 * 
 */
 
.panel-multicomplete-results {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 420px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(mc-bg.png) repeat-y;
}

.panel-multicomplete-results .result {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-multicomplete-results .result:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.panel-multicomplete-results .group {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.panel-multicomplete-results .group:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.panel-multicomplete-results .group-title {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-multicomplete-results .group-items {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* UTILITIES */
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     Start typing a city: <input type="text" name="multiselect" id="input-multicomplete" />
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ynyqed1m/